# Need to call didStartSending on insertText method in iMessage Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created an iMessage app to send image with link. and i don't want the receiver to compulsorily have the same application.

In IMessage extension is there any way to call MSMessagesAppViewController didStartSending overridden method without using insert method to send message.

Below code are using for send messages on imessages extension.

```
guard let conversation = activeConversation else { fatalError("Expected a  conversation") }
let strUrl = "https://www.google.com/"
let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
        layout.image = image
        layout.imageTitle = imageName
        layout.caption = strUrl

        let msgToSend = MSMessage()
        msgToSend.url = URL.init(string: strUrl)
        msgToSend.layout = layout

      //  conversation.insert(msgToSend, completionHandler: {(error) in
      //      print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
      //  })
        conversation.insertText(strUrl, completionHandler: { (error) in
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Is using `insertText` compulsory?

It seems you can use `sendText()` method that will directly send the text message without putting it on using the `iMessage` text field.

Hope this works.

```
    conversation.sendText(strUrl, completionHandler: { (error) in
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    })
```